# Creates an employee record in a time and attendance database and returns the employee object

Tags: c#, object-oriented, database

I am writing a time and attendance system.  This is my idea of a simple elegant solution for the employee class. To me it makes the client very simple an encapsulates everything it needs, however I an new to Object Orientated Design and would appreciate a review.  I plan to create the other classes like this but fear there may be a better way.

My employee class...

```
 class Employee
    {
        public static Employee CreateNew(string forename, string surname)
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee(forename, surname);
            AddToDataBase(employee);
            return employee;
        }

        public string Forename { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }


        private Employee(string forename, string surname)
        {
            this.Forename = forename;
            this.Surname = surname;
        }

        private static void AddToDataBase(Employee employee)
        {
          //code to add employee to database  

        }
    }
```

usage...

```
Employee.CreateNew("Bob", "Smith");
```

Comment: I'd recommend reading this http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ though for this case it likely isn't a major concern

Comment: I wouldn't save right away. Usually we fill up the business object, check for business rule and later save to the database.

Comment: Your example might be pseudo code but you really should name your properties as `Forename`, `Surname`.

Comment: i usually do, amended now

Comment: At first glance, something seems bad: How do you read an `Employee` back from the DB? Using `CreateNew` will result in a duplicate in the DB, so the only option is to call the private constructor though reflection, breaking encapsulation (unless there is more code to handle that not shown here).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is common practice to use static methods-creators instead of constructors. But this approach is used in cases where you need to convert some objects to the object of desired type. It is the main reason for such methods – conversion from one representation to another.

But you use your `CreateNew` method for side effects and it is not good in my opinion. If I call `CreateNew` I'll expect just to get a new instance of the `Employee`. I don't expect that this method will do something else.

I would create method `AddNewEmployeeAndAddToDB` but **not in the `Employee` class**. Adding to database is not a part of employee functionality.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Maxim's answer, to avoid giving the employee class too much responsibilities, by adding the AddToDataBase method there, you could take a look at the repository pattern.

[Repository pattern explained.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985736/repository-pattern-step-by-step-explanation)

This pattern is created to handle database management.

Comment: never even heard of that and I have been looking for some.  'best followed practices. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that everybody has exactly one "forename" and one "surname", your code should probably reference where that decision was made (and, ideally, explain how to work around that where it's not valid).

It may well be useful to include additional unique information (payroll number, National Insurance number, or similar) to help distinguish between pairs of employees who have identical names.

Comment: In that version the database auto generated an employee id.